# Does the GDPR cover reviewer blacklists, and if so, how?

Tags: peer-review, conference, interpersonal-issues, legal-issues, anonymity

I've served as an area chair for several conferences.  Following the review period, the program chairs asked the area chairs to submit to them an annotated list of problematic reviewers. Mostly these were reviewers who failed to submit a review at all, despite repeated reminders, but we were also asked to identify reviewers who submitted exceptionally low-quality reviews, such as reviews that were so short/vague as to be useless, and reviews whose factual errors were so glaring that it was obvious that the reviewer either lacked even the bare minimum subject-matter knowledge, or else didn't bother reading the paper at all.  The purpose of collecting these lists was to construct or to supplement a blacklist for use with future program committee invitations.  That is, people on these blacklists would not be invited to review for future conferences operated by the same scholarly society.

I am wondering whether the coming into force of the EU/EEA [General Data Protection Regulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation) has any implications for these blacklists.  In particular, is the blacklist itself considered "personal information", and is it even lawful to compile such a list?  Can the reviewers mentioned on this list use the provisions of the GDPR to force its maintainers to disclose their presence on the list or even to remove them from the list?  How about the area chair comments used to construct the list—are these something that blacklisted reviewers can force the conference organizers to turn over to them?

I realize that this is a question about legal principles and practice, and so might be also (or maybe even better) appropriate for the [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/) or a lawyer.  But since the question treats a uniquely academic scenario, I'm hoping that someone here might belong to a scholarly society that has already looked into the matter, and can therefore provide a brief summary for the present academic audience.

Comment: You are right, this is a law question.

Comment: And yet we have a dedicated tag here for [legal issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-issues), so I figured I'd try posting here first.  I'm not in urgent need of professional legal advice; I'm asking more out of curiosity and long-term planning (in case I ever decide to organize a conference myself).

Comment: A question being about law does not make it more or less on topic.

Comment: I think the question is on topic, but I think it's weird to post it here.

Comment: I think this is an awesome question. Let's hope we get good answers for it.

Comment: Is making a blacklist even legal to begin with? I know that there are a number of US states that flat-up ban employer blacklists.

Comment: @nick012000 There is no employment contract here. Reviewers are volunteers.

Comment: I have voted to close as off-topic in the hope that the question will be moved to law.sx where I expect that the probability to obtain good answers by someone who knows the legal intricacies is higher. In that case, we'd still have the link to that question here, so anyone searching for answers on academia will find it.

Answer (score 2):

The GDPR of course doesn't cover all possible scenarios. However, it's fairly logical. You're **not** allowed to have and use personal information, **unless** you meet at least 1 of 6 specific reasons. "Consent" is the best-known, because we've all been asked hundreds of times in the last year. But obviously that's not going to fly for a blacklist.

No, the reason which can justify a blacklist is (6e) processing is necessary for the performance of a task carried out in the public interest or in the exercise of official authority vested in the controller. Academic publishing is probably not done "in the exercise of official authority", but it definitely is "a task carried out in the public interest".

Having established that there's a reason, most of the other GDPR requirements become technical. There's a right to ask for *factual* corrections, but if the facts are in dispute you only need to record the objection. You are not forced to decide.

Now the biggy is of course the "right to be forgotten"/right to erasure. This is not an unconditional right. The person invoking this right must state a reason, and this must hold. "Withdrawing consent" is a reason, but it only applies when consent was originally necessary, which is not the case for the blacklist. "No longer necessary" might make sense if someone retires entirely, but we know that in academia retirement is often not a black&white matter.

The good thing here is that you can reason about actual removal requests if and when they arrive. There is not much preparation required other than the general GDPR rules for good recordkeeping.

Comment: My guess would be that irrespective of whether their might be a case that could be argued in court, whoever carries the (financial) liability for a finding against the conference organizers, or just the cost of defending such a claim, would not want to even see the case be brought.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that GDPR also means that keeping such a list would mean having to inform people who are on the list?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft AIUI, not proactively. But if a person on the list asked about the list, the organisation would have to tell them.

Comment: @Flyto Ok. That is not my understanding of it, but I never did go into much detail. I know we send out letters with details of how we treat data to everyone who gets added to the system I work on (since I just had the task of automating that process). But I don't know if we are required to send out those or just do.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft my understanding is that you're not required to send it out, but that information it must be available. But I'm not a lawyer or an expert on GDPR, so I may be wrong.

Comment: @IanSudbery: What sort of financial liability are you considering? There's no profit in reviewing, so it's pretty hard to claim damages. As for the theoretical risk of being sued, you can also be sued _now_ on the mere allegation that you have a blacklist. That's a general principle in law; there's little that you can do that can prevent lawsuits from being filed. The best you can achieve is to make it hard for your opponent to find a lawyer.

Comment: My understanding (and perhaps you know better than me) is that breach of GDPR carry fines independent of damages. Certainly if you were sued over having a blacklist you'd surely be in a better position if you didn't have one, even if you might argue that having one is justified if you did.  I certainly know that at our institution they are taking it very seriously and very much taking a precautionary approach (prohibiting anything that might in any way smell slightly like something someone might complain about).

Comment: While I see how one could argue for public interest (though I'm not sure even for that) I don't see the *necessity*: organizing reviews without blacklist is *possible* even though somewhat more tedious if some of the non-answers/useless reports can be avoided by using the blacklist.

Comment: I also disagree that consent wouldn't work here: consent may be asked in a more neutral fashion to keep a file of reviewers together with performance data (would probably need to be described in a more specific fashion) on the reviews delivered (and e.g. areas of expertise) for the purpose of easing the task of finding reviewers for future editions of the conference. Such a list would be even better than a blacklist for the organizers and at the same time more transparent to the reviewers (who'd then also know whom to address their GDPR questions & requests to).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force editors to use de facto bad reviewers if they know about them.

However, the actual problem with today's ease of data collection is that you can easily accumulate lots of (possibly low-quality and unvetted) data; a blacklist being sent around can constitute slander (or whatever you call it in your jurisdiction), even independently of GDPR. IANAL, but in my understanding, GDPR might be used by a person suspecting blacklisting to force the organisers to reveal its existence and one's presence on it, even if its transfer from one years' organiser to next years' organiser could be justified under its rules. With a cascade of further legal consequences in its wake which are not just limited to removal from the list.

I do not know if they can have a look at the blacklisting comments, but if the comments are sent around with the blacklist between year committees, I estimate that they fall under GDPR.

Having some basic rules of data hygiene (and I consider GDPR as such) is not an entirely bad thing. Best is, leave yourself extra time to get additional reviews if reviews are not up to scratch and don't send blacklists around.

**TL;DR** GDPR, as I understand it (IANAL), permits people to ask their presence on a blacklist to be revealed, especially if it is institutional (i.e. sent around between organisation committees, not just for individual use of the particular editor).

Comment: But a major additional question is whether keeping such a list is even allowed by GDPR, since it will (by necessity) contain information that can identify people. It might be allowed, since there is a reason for it, but that would still probably involve some serious thought to data security and who has access to the list.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Absolutely. If the list is leaked, the organisers could end up in very serious trouble (not because something is leaked that shouldn't be there, but because the list becomes visible to people who shouldn't be privy to it).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft organisations can retain personal information so long as they have a "legitimate interest" in having it. One could argue that there is legitimate interest in having lists of bad reviewers when organising a conference. But it does have to be treated with the same care and thought as other personal data.